# White dots / blemish in LED monitor repairable?

Tags: display, led

This 10-year old LED monitor has white dots / blemishes on its screen. Is this still repairable or does the panel needs replacement?

[image: e]

More pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image compression makes it super hard to tell what this is. It could be dust, it could be insect feces, it could be the display’s internal connectors…

Comment: Looks like someone has cleaned it with a very inappropriate cleaning agent. Nothing to do but replace it.

Comment: @DanielB The image is quite close the real thing specially the white dots or "noise".

Comment: All I see is compression artifacts, sorry. Please take a high-resolution close-up photo from the front and from an angle, so we can judge the physical properties of the dots. Currently, it’s impossible to tell whether they’re pixels or dirt inside the panel or dirt on the panel or acid burns on the panel or whatever.

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately I am unable to shoot a high-res pic but I added a few more in the desc.

Comment: From an angle it looks like thousands of tiny craters in the surface. So probably what Peregrino69 said!

Comment: @DanielB Alright thank you!

Comment: Without knowing where it was stored it's hard to guess what it could be. Could be mould, salt crystals, sand abrasion, some corrosive spray or cleaner or any number of other things. What is the texture like? Is it smooth, suggesting that the blemishes are within the panel, or is it rough as if the outer plastic layer is damaged. Please [edit] your question to add more information and better pictures if possible.